# Defend autocorrelation in VAR model

Tags: autocorrelation, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I am creating an unrestricted VAR model with 9 variables and 12 lags (determined by LR, FPE and AIC, and is in line with theory). But the model still has some autocorrelation - the p-values of some of the lags are less than 0.05 and on the others are higher than 0.05.

I am afraid that adding more lags will lead to model overfitting, and will also complicate the model additionally.

What can i do to get rid of the autocorrelation, or what can i write in order to 'defend' the autocorrelation in my model?

Comment: How to "defend" your model depends on what you are trying to accomplish, and how well it accomplishes this specific objective. Are you trying to forecast, or make inference about the parameters, for example? Also, how long are your series? Does the theory really say "should depend on lags 1 through 12", or "should depend on 12th lag", as in a seasonal monthly series?

Comment: I am trying to define the direction of the effect, and that is why i mainly focus on IRF. Each of the series counts 144 observations, and the theory says - changes in monetary policy have their effect on the real activity after 9 - 16 months.